# Copy a string only if that string includes a number on a specific position

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a string into my Excel sheet, but only when the 7th position of that string `myString` is `"4"`.
The string `myString` has always the format: S123456789. So the first position of `myString` is always the same letter "S", the following positions are always numbers that can be changed.

```
Dim myString As String

    If InStr(7, myString, "4") > 0 Then

    'do nothing
    
    Else
    
    'copy myString into my Excel sheet

End If
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: `If Mid(myString, 7,1)="4" Then ...` ?

Comment: ... or using your idea `If InStr(7, myString, "4") = 7 Then` or `If myString Like "S#####4###" Then`...